# How can I show Checkbox and Input element inside the same td and in same line

Tags: html, asp.net-core

Is there any way can I show the Input Number and Checkbox  inside the same td element of the table  and same line ? . When I am trying to show , The input element skip to next line.
Checkbox should be shown just left side of the Input but in same line of the TD column Here is  the code given below

```
EmpModel
EmpName string 
IsSlarySuccess boolean
Salary decimal(5,2)
IsBonusSuccess boolean
Bonus decimal(5,2)
```

```html
@model List<EmpModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Bonus</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
             <tr>
            <td>@Model[i].EmpName</td>
                     <td><input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" asp-for="@Model[i].Salary" class="form-control format-text" />
                                         <span style="float:left"><input type="checkbox" @(Model.[i].IsSlarySuccess ? "checked" : "") /></span>
             <td><input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" asp-for="@Model[i].Bonus" class="form-control format-text" />
                                         <span style="float:left"><input type="checkbox" @(Model.[i].IsBonusSuccess ? "checked" : "") /></span>
            </tr>

        }
         
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Yes and your code example does exactly that.

Comment: Jon , but  my code doesnot work, Input Number element going to next line. Checkbox is being showed top of the Input box. That should be shown in same line

Comment: Running the code snippet, everything is in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[.form-inline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms)** class can display a series of labels, form controls, and buttons **on a single**

**horizontal row.**

So you can add the input and span in a new div which class is **form-inline** and put the

element in the order you want, like:

```
<tr>
        <td>EmpName</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <span><input type="checkbox" /></span>
                <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <span><input type="checkbox" /></span>
                <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**Edit:**

If you have more td, you can **write a css** like this :

```
<style>
#showinline {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
</style>

<table>
  //....
      <td>
          <div id="showinline">  //use that css here
              <span><input type="checkbox" /></span>
              <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" />
          </div>
      </td>
  //............more
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Tisa,  But when I add more  td column , the Input Number going to next line. It is working  if there is  five or  six column, But if I add more column , the input box going to next line. Is there any way can we  align Span item and Input box together in same line .

Comment: @AlanPauil I have edited my post, try css now

Comment: Many Thanks . That's perfect